# JSON String to class matching not working in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core-2.1

this JSON String from Post Request:

```
{"nbr":3,"name":"Standort 3","siteID":0,"state":0,"dateCreated":""}
```

cannot be matched with this c# class:

```
public class Site
    {   
        public int Nbr { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int SiteID { get; set; }
        public int State { get; set; }
        public string DateCreated { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a similar more complex class which is working.

Comment: change your json parameters to upper case then try  again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is fine, probably may be you missed out [FromBody] on the controller that will receive the request. If you can share the part of the controller that will receive the request, we would be able to help you better

Comment: Hi Olbuoye, you're right. I had troubles in the past using the [FromBody] Attribute, so I have not used it in that case. That's the mistake. I also don't understand why it works with an similar class and a copy of this controller, but anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the case in order for it to work, i.e. your JSON has to start upper case. 
There could also be a problem with the DateTime parsing, but probably it's the case  sensitivity. So if fixing to uppercase dosnt work make sure you convert the DataTime correctly.

Comment: Hi René, thank you for your answer. Thankfully the controller is smart enough to deal with that. If you serialize a class with uppercase Properties, the serialized string will begin with lowercase letter (Nbr -> nbr)

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize it with Newtonsoft.Json library . it works for me

like this :

```
var xJson = "{ 'nbr':3,'name':'Standort 3','siteID':0,'state':0,'dateCreated':''}";

var xPars = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Site>(xJson);
```

Comment: You are right, thank you! The problem was the missing [FromBody] Attribut in the controller class.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the mistake was missing set attributes on the constructor.

```
    public SomeClass(
        string param1,
        int param2,
        bool param3,
        string param4
    ) 
    {
        this.param1= param1; 
        //param2 is missing...
        this.param3 = param3;
        this.param4 = param4;

        
    }
```